# Why would the numberpad on my keyboard sometimes not work?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a **USB keyboard** and a normal keyboard.

I have **Windows 7** and a USB keyboard.

I turn on my computer and the keyboard works **fine** for awhile, then all of a **sudden** the **position** keys do not work on the **numeric pad** (like 8 for Up, 4 for Left, 6 for Right, and so on):

[image: Numeric keypad]

I can hit NUM (to enable Num Lock) and the **numbers work**, but then if I hit NUM again (to disable Num Lock), the position keys on the numeric keypad don't work again.

I can plug in a normal keyboard, and it acts the same way.

**How I can get my position keys on my keyboard(s) to always work?**

Comment: What is a normal keyboard for you? Or asked differently: What's un-normal with a USB keyboard?

Comment: @Johannes: I would hazard that normal=PS2

Comment: What make is your computer? For a laptop the Fn key can sometimes do funny things.

Comment: Does this happen across all applications, ie it's not program-specific?

Comment: @kbmonkey, I've determined that it just goes off and on randomly, currently I can use the numeric pad arrow keys in this box, but 5 minutes ago in this same box I couldn't, it goes on and off in all applications, and when it was off once I took out this USB keyboard and plugged in my PS/2 (what I called "normal" above) and the numeric pad arrow keys didn't work on that either, so it seems like it is an Operating System thing or perhaps, e.g. I have about 8 devices plugged in my USB ports and a WACOM art pen, perhaps interference? Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me answer my own question, since this was really odd, but had a happy ending:

I noticed that when I would type the word "another", the cursor would "come alive", erase the word, and retype it as another word, e.g. somethings "anotherr" and sometimes "anrother". This was so odd that at first I just sat back in disbelief, then called my wife into the room so that she could confirm that, indeed, it was happening.

The problem turned out to be that I had installed the latest version of [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software/texter/lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php), a program that enables you to define windows-wide macros so that when you type e.g. "sigg" and press the space bar, it will erase the word "sigg" and type out a signature for letters. Apparently this program has a problem with Windows 7 or a problem in general that was just causing it to freak out in subtle ways.

**In any case, as soon as I uninstalled Texter, no more numeric pad arrow problems.**