# What is the best multi-application macro tool for windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macros

I used to use [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software/texter/lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php) as a program to create **text macros** that can be used in any application, e.g. so you can type "sigg" followed by the **space bar** and it would replace the word with your signature that you can include at the bottom of letters, etc. I used this for **code blocks**, long names, etc. Very useful.

However, the latest version causes [subtly odd behaviors on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/58719/why-would-the-numberpad-on-my-keyboard-sometimes-not-work) which makes it unusable so I **uninstalled** it.

If no one has a good answer, I'll go back to [ac'tivAid](http://www.heise.de/ct/projekte/Windows-weitergedacht-ac-tivAid-284115.html), a collection of tools (in German) which does about 100 other things as well but is a bit overkill for just getting the macro functionality.

**Does anyone know of another program that enables keyboard macros that can be triggered simply by typing text followed by a SPACE or TAB?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) is the answer you want.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey):

> AutoHotkey scripts can be used to launch programs, open documents, send keystrokes and send mouse clicks and movements[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey). AutoHotkey scripts can also assign, retrieve, and manipulate variables, run loops and manipulate windows, files, and folders. These commands can be triggered by a hotkey, such as a script that would open an internet browser whenever the user presses Ctrl+Alt+i on the keyboard. Keyboard keys can also be remapped or disabled, such that pressing the letter q, for example, might result in the computer receiving an r, or nothing at all[3]. **AutoHotkey also allows for 'hotstrings' that will automatically replace certain text as it typed; the most typical use for hotstrings is expanding abbreviations, such as assigning the string "btw" to send the text "by the way" when typed.**

Comment: AutoHotkey! What else? ;-)

Comment: yes, that is yet, where have I been? I remember reading that ac'tivAid required autohotkey to be installed, I guess it was just a layer on top of it, in any case, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been very impressed with PhraseExpress.  I use v8.0.134 and I've found the ramp-up time and effort to be very small.  It allows the creation of new text insertions using Ctrl-Alt-C and I make new ones regularly.

I'm still looking to get into using AutoHotKey for some of the other features mentioned in a previous answer (e.g. launching programs).